# select attr from adjacent class with a specific name

Tags: html, jquery

my html is structured like so:

```
<div class='quiz-question'>
 <div name='qc-1' class='btn quiz-choice ' >3</div>
 <div name='qc-2' class='btn quiz-choice correct' >4</div>
 <div name='qc-3' class='btn quiz-choice ' >5</div>
</div>
```

i want to use jquery to select the `name` attribute from the `correct` div when you click on ANY of the `quiz-choice` divs.

so no matter which one i click on i'd like to get the value of the name from whichever one has the `correct` class

i think it should be something like this but it keeps coming back as undefined.

```
jQuery('.quiz-choice').click(function(){
 var correctChoice = $(this).parent('.quiz-question').children('.quiz-choice').hasClass('correct').attr('name');
});
```

Comment: Divs have no `name` attribute. Use a `data-*` attribute instead. That said, use `.children('.quiz-choice.correct')` instead of `children('.quiz-choice').hasClass('correct')` and it will work

Comment: thank you, that worked. i also switched name to a data-* attribute.